# Producing a more efficient for loop

Tags: r, performance, for-loop

I have created a function which applies a Cox regression model to test data, creates survival functions based on covariates, and then predicts the survival probability 30 days from current time for each test observation.

The example below uses the lung dataset and works quite well. However, applied to my own data the processing time is tedious. For n = 60000, I just stopped it after an hour as it is not practical for what I intend to use the program for.

Looking at the code structure, is there an obvious way I can speed this up?

```
require(dplyr, survival, pec)

cox_model <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)

surv_preds <- function(model, query) {

  prediction <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = nrow(query))
  time <- 30

  for(i in 1:nrow(query)) {
    prediction[i] <- predictSurvProb(model, newdata = query[i, ], times = query[i, "time"] + time)
  }
  prediction
}

surv_preds(cox_model, lung)
```

Comment: You should also tag your post as `[r]`.

Comment: Done. Thank you.

Comment: Where are you getting `lung` data from?

Comment: survival package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!! In case it is of interest, I want to post the solution that I used. I managed to remove the need for the for loop entirely.

```
predictSurvProb(cox_model, 
                newdata = lung, 
                times = lung[ , "time"] + 30)[1, ]
```

This gives me the output I require. The key is that I index the first row and all its columns from the resulting matrix. This code uses the unique survival function estimate for each observation to predict the survival probability 30 days from the observation's current position on the curve.

The answer from @thc actually pointed me in the right direction in the end.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate route would be the `by_row` function from `purrrlyr` in addition to the packages in the question.

```
library(purrrlyr)

prediction <- lung %>%
  mutate(time = time + 30) %>%
  by_row(~predictSurvProb(cox_model, newdata = ., times = .$time)) %>%
  .$.out %>%
  unlist
```

It is more *tidy* while producing the same result, however, early runs of `microbenchmark` don't show an improvement in processing time.

#### microbenchmark

```
# Unit: seconds
#                        expr      min       lq    mean   median       uq      max neval
# surv_preds(cox_model, lung) 1.531631 1.561518 1.59431 1.574664 1.591117 2.157002   100
# (purrrlyr)                  1.841713 1.887438 1.921371 1.90474 1.92649  2.170205   100
```

This would have both solutions running over 24 hours on the hardware I'm using. 
 Given this answer no longer seems to solve your problem and I am unfamiliar with parallel processing options I'm happy to delete this unless anyone finds value in keeping this here.

Comment: Thank you for your input.I can't seem to find a solution for this. The purrrly example is nice but unfortunately would still be too slow for my intended purpose. If all comes to all, it may be my only option.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to predict one row at a time.  You can do it all at once.  E.g.:

```
cox_model <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)

surv_preds <- function(model, query) {

  prediction <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = nrow(query))
  time <- 30

  for(i in 1:nrow(query)) {
    prediction[i] <- predictSurvProb(model, newdata = query[i, ], times = query[i, "time"] + time)
  }
  prediction
}

surv_preds2 <- function(model, query) {

time <- 30

prediction <- predictSurvProb(model, newdata = query, times = query[, "time"] + time)
  prediction
}


microbenchmark(surv_preds(cox_model, lung), surv_preds2(cox_model, lung), times=5)
```

Results:

```
Unit: milliseconds
                         expr       min         lq      mean     median         uq        max neval cld
  surv_preds(cox_model, lung) 1017.5587 1031.58422 1056.7026 1062.30476 1072.33865 1099.72672     5   b
 surv_preds2(cox_model, lung)   30.3567   30.78582   35.7851   31.81206   33.00534   52.96559     5  a
```

Comment: This is actually not what I need. This code passes a vector of times to predict but I need just a single time passed to each test instance which is its time + 30 days.

Comment: You can do the same thing.  Just change query so that each row is a each test instance.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you implement it in the code example I have given?

Comment: The main difference is that I need to take an observation's current time and add 30 days to that to get a unique survival probability. For example, if I have 3 test queries who are currently alive at 100, 200 and 250 days, I now need the survival probability at day 130 for query 1, 230 days for query 2 and 280 days for query 3. Your method above passes a vector 130, 230, 250 to each query giving three probabilities for each one and forming a matrix when I just want a vector returned.

Comment: Yes, but even though it is doing redundant calculation, it is still much faster.  I updated the code above and provided the benchmark for proof.  You can extract out the vector you want by sorting the times.

Comment: @thc, I may be missing something but the results of the two functions are not equal. `surv_preds2[1, ] == surv_preds2[2, ]` but `surv_preds != surv_preds2[1, ]`, even after sorting